# How to let webview have default blank above all content?

Tags: android, webview

I have some specail requirement which need webview have default blank on the top,like this pic:
[image]

And the blank's should be the part of webview's content so that it can be scrolled. And I had thought to add a blank  in html. But I can't find any function to get current html of webview.

So, is there any way to create a blank with specific height before all html content in webview ?

**UPDATE**:I found the solution:[FadingActionBar](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar)

Comment: @MSGadag Only a webview.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="100dp" /> // update ur desired height

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the content of webview won't show in the padding area.I want the padding area liking the part of content in webview.